# Игнорировать \s \t \n javascript регулярные выражения

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, match

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как игнорировать строку, где есть пробелы (\s), табуляции (\t), переносы строк (\n) и нет никакого другого символа?

Comment: Игнорировать = удалить их из строки?

Comment: Нет, чтоб была просто проверка.

Comment: Не понимаю. Вот есть у вас строка "привет, друг". Чего вы хотите? Чтобы проверка вернула `true`, так как там есть пробел?

Comment: Допустим есть такая строка '  '; в ней только пробелы. и если поставить условие `if ( '   '.match( /[\s\t\n]/gi ) )` то если только они присутствуют, то игнорировать условие.

Comment: `if(/^\s+$/.test(yourString)){ /* Только пробельные символы */ }`.

Comment: +Other Отличный пример. Спасибо большое. Напишите его в ответе, я за него проголосую, как правильный

Comment: `if (s.trim() === '') { /*пробелы*/ }`

Comment: @Other, ответы - в ответы.

Comment: @johndws, поздно, уже дали хороший ответ, плюсуйте ему :)

Comment: @Qwertiy, а фабрики - java-программистам?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы хотите реализовать проверку всей строки на [пробельные символы](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Zs/list.htm), то можно обойтись и без регулярных выражений с помощью [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim):

```js
var s = "\u0020\u00A0\u1680\u2000\u2001\u2002\u2003\u2004\u2005\u2006\u2007\u2008\u2009\u200A\u202F\u205F\u3000\t";
console.log("Исходная строка: '", s, "'");
if (s.trim() === '') { 
  console.log('Строка содержит только пробельные символы!');
}
```

Если вам обязательно нужно именно регулярное выражение, используйте [решение Other](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/734478/%D0%98%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-s-t-n-javascript-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#comment1117510_734478).

Если необходимо проверить, состоит ли строка только из конкретных пробельных символов, например, знака табуляции, перевода каретки и перехода на новую строку, можно использовать символьный класс:

```
if (/^[\t\r\n]+$/.test(s)) { /* строка содержит только \t, \n и/или \r */ }
```

Тут

- `^` - начало строки
- `[\t\r\n]+` - один и более знаков табуляции, перевода каретки и перехода на новую строку
- `$` - конец строки.

Класс `[\t\r\n]` можно заменить на `\s`, если необходимо сделать проверку на все пробельные символы.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Очень хороший вариант. Но я сделал чуть по другому: `if ( string.replace( /\s|\t|\n/, '' ) != '' )`

Comment: @johndws 2 замечания: 1) `string.replace( /\s|\t|\n/, '' )` удалит только один любой пробельный символ в строке, 2) в выражении `/\s|\t|\n/` используется группа альтернатив для одиночных символов - это т.н. "overkill", так как для этого и созданы символьные классы. НО вам даже символьный класс не нужен, т.к. `/\s|\t|\n/` = `/\s/`. Короче, `/\s+/g` был бы наилучшим решением в вашем стиле, а самым лучшим (а главное, эквивалентным вашему) является `if (s.trim() === '')`.

Comment: Ок. Спасибо за разъяснение. Мне ещё многое в регулярках не понятно. Со временем думаю, будет более понятней что да как.